# Combining several SHEETS into one EXCEL

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx, worksheet

I am using this code to put all Excel files and sheets into one. And it works flawlessly. But in some occasions i want to take all the excel files, and only put all the sheets from all the files into a single excel file. I know i can use Copy sheet in excel, but I want to do it to multiple documents. **Keep all the data as it was, no added columns or rows, and keep the name of the sheet aswell**. I am sure pandas has such a function, so I do not do it manually. If you have an idea please help.
Example:
Workbook1
Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3

Workbook2
Sheet11
Sheet22

Apply code...

FinalWorkbook
Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
Sheet11
Sheet22

This code puts all the data into a single sheet.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
print("Combine xls and xlsx")
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
## get all sheets of a given file
df_total = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:                         # loop through Excel files
    if file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(file)
        sheets = excel_file.sheet_names
        for sheet in sheets:               # loop through sheets inside an Excel file
            print (file, sheet)
            df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name = sheet)
            df_total = df_total.append(df)
print("Loaded, ENTER to combine:")
dali=input()
df_total.to_excel('Combined/combined_file.xlsx')
print("Done")
dali=input()
```

Comment: try instead of `df_total = df_total.append(df)` to use `df.to_excel('Combined/combined_file.xlsx', sheet_name=f"{file}_{sheet}")`

Comment: forgot to mention, of course, remove the row `df_total.to_excel('Combined/combined_file.xlsx')` at the bottom of your code  during the test above

Comment: That does not work, it saves the last sheet only. Not all of them. And there is a column added at the start of the data.

Comment: I think I cracked it, I needed to use a writer to have several sheets. ``with pd.ExcelWriter("Combined/combined_file.xlsx",mode='a') as writer:  
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"{sheet}")``

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add "solved" or similar to the question. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). In about 2 days you can accept your own answer, showing that you indeed "solved" this.

Comment: Okay, I already did that. Thank you, won't do solved titles in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer. I hope someone finds this useful. Combines all sheets from all excel files XLS od XLSX to a single excel file with all sheets.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
print("Copying sheets from multiple files to one file")
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  

df_total = pd.DataFrame()
df_total.to_excel('Combined/combined_file.xlsx') #create a new file
workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook('Combined/combined_file.xlsx')
ss_sheet = workbook['Sheet1']
ss_sheet.title = 'TempExcelSheetForDeleting'
workbook.save('Combined/combined_file.xlsx')


for file in files:                         # loop through Excel files
    if file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(file)
        sheets = excel_file.sheet_names
        for sheet in sheets:               # loop through sheets inside an Excel file
            print (file, sheet)
            df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name = sheet)
            with pd.ExcelWriter("Combined/combined_file.xlsx",mode='a') as writer:  
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"{sheet}", index=False)
            #df.to_excel("Combined/combined_file.xlsx", sheet_name=f"{sheet}")

workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook('Combined/combined_file.xlsx')
std=workbook["TempExcelSheetForDeleting"]
workbook.remove(std)
workbook.save('Combined/combined_file.xlsx')
print("Loaded, press ENTER to end")
dali=input()
#df_total.to_excel('Combined/combined_file.xlsx')
print("Done")
dali=input()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78240565/algorithm-becomes-slow-after-a-few-excel-files