# Algorithm becomes slow after a few excel files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

### **Problem overview**

I need to combine several .xlsx files into sheets, where each sheet name must be the file name.

---

**Current issue**

The code below, becomes slow and spends a lot of memory after a few files.

---

**Attempted solution**

Closing excel file and deleting dataframe and running gc manually, does not work.

**code**

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import os
import gc as gc

print("Copying sheets from multiple files to one file")

dir_input = 'D:/MeusProjetosJava/Importacao/'
dir_output = "Integrados/combined.xlsx"

cwd = os.path.abspath(dir_input)
files = os.listdir(cwd)

df_total = pd.DataFrame()
df_total.to_excel(dir_output) #create a new file
workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(dir_output)
ss_sheet = workbook['Sheet1']
ss_sheet.title = 'TempExcelSheetForDeleting'
workbook.save(dir_output)


for file in files:                         # loop through Excel files
    if file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(cwd+"/"+file)
        sheets = excel_file.sheet_names
        for sheet in sheets:
            sheet_name = str(file.title())
            sheet_name = sheet_name.replace(".xlsx","").lower()
            sheet_name = sheet_name.removesuffix(".xlsx")

            print(file, sheet_name)

            df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name = sheet)
            with pd.ExcelWriter(dir_output,mode='a') as writer:
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"{sheet_name}", index=False)
                del df

        excel_file.close()
        del excel_file
        sheets = None
        gc.collect()


workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(dir_output)
std=workbook["TempExcelSheetForDeleting"]
workbook.remove(std)
workbook.save(dir_output)
print("all done")
```

** References **

[Combining several SHEETS into one EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73539271/combining-several-sheets-into-one-excel)

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is a bit convoluted and creating some unnecessary temporary objects. I would try with a simple approach first that is  use Pandas ExcelWriter so template code will be something like this. Are your files really big that its causing memory issue ??

```
# Don't like the dir_output name as its the final file output name
with pd.ExcelWriter(dir_output , mode='a') as writer:
    for file in files:                         
        if file.endswith('.xls') or file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            # get the name of the file in cur_sheet YOUR CODE
            df = pd.read_excel(file)
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=cur_sheet)
```